# How to set textarea with width of content?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, textarea, semantic-ui

I'm using react semantic ui textarea and I want to set width based on its content. min-width doesn't help. Any ideas?

```
<Textarea
        key={idx}
        defaultValue={formattedText}
        className="customInput"
        maxLength="100"
        name={idx}
        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
      />
```

Comment: I think you will need to write a function (onChange => Calculate width). Semantic Ui doesn't have any out-of-box solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind style attr in vue like below

```
<Textarea :style="widthContent"/>
export default {
    computed:{
     widthContent(){
       //caculate your width here
       return {width: ...px}
     }
   }
}
```

More details:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html